# How to insert leading spaces/tabs in yasnippet?

Tags: yasnippet

yasnippet does not respect spaces or tabs when they occur at the start a line.

In my snippet file I have

```
   example
```

which executes as

```
example
```

Escaping with `\` doesn't work.

How do I get leading spaces/tabs?

Answer (score 7):

Look for `expand-env: ((yas-indent-line 'fixed))`:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: Example for Indent
# key: example
# expand-env: ((yas-indent-line 'fixed))
# --
    example
$0
```